# How to use Autobahn js with Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using a service which relies on Autobahn but I get sporadic drops in my calls.

```
import autobahn from 'autobahn';
var connection = new autobahn.Connection({
  url: 'ws://host.docker.internal:8080/service',
  realm: 'realm1',
  protocols: ['wamp.2.json']
});

//Attempt 1 - opening the connection at the beginning and using it for all calls
connection.open();
connection.onopen = async function (session)
{
  console.log('Connection established');
}

connection.onclose = function (reason) {
  if (reason !== 'lost') {
    console.log("Connection closed. Reason: " + reason);
  }
};

function createObject(obj)
{
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  {
    // Attempt 2 - tried opening the connection here but when I call the method      
    // multiple times I don't get the service to interact correctly.
    connection.onopen = async function (session)
    {
      console.log('Creating new object');
      session.call('service.object.create', [], obj).then(
        function (res)
        {
          resolve();
        },
        function (error)
        {
          console.log(error);
          reject(error)
        }
      )
    }
  })
}

export { createObject }
```

I have a total of 4 methods similar to `createObject` for other interactions with the service - delete, search, etc.

I tried to open the connection at the top of the file hoping to use it in the methods, however, `console.log("Creating new object')` does not trigger in the `createObject` method. I also tried opening the connection and closing the connection every time when I call a method, but that leads to dropped events.

**Edit**

I tried the following and it seems to work, but it looks hacky. Is this the correct way?

```
var session
connection.open();
connection.onopen = async function (ses)
{
  session.ses
  console.log('Connection established');
}
```

Comment: It makes sense that `connection.onopen` doesn't run in your `createObject` function: by the time you call the function, the connection has already been opened.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you want to use it with Promises? Event based systems can fire multiple times, Promises only work once when executed. Besides, events are already asynchronous. What is the benefit?

Comment: I am using `await` in another method, which waits for the promise in autobahn to resolve before proceeding. Something like `await createObject(data); await deleteObject(obj); await getObject(obj);` - all of these call the methods, which call the autobahn service. Am I completely missing the point?

Comment: Nah, you're good. The implementation should just be a bit different. I've attempted to create a solution. Feel free to let me know if it is what you needed or if it needs some work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in that the `onopen` event only runs once, when you open the connection. The active session will from then by either available in the `onopen` event handler or within `connection.session`. [source](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-js/blob/master/doc/reference.md#connection-properties)

I'd suggest to open your connection and then export the `connection` object. This way you can use the active session in the other files by importing `connection` there.

```
// connection.js
import autobahn from 'autobahn';

const connection = new autobahn.Connection({
  url: 'ws://host.docker.internal:8080/service',
  realm: 'realm1',
  protocols: ['wamp.2.json']
});

connection.onopen = await function (session) {
  session.log('Session has been opened');
}

connection.onclose = function (reason) {
  if (reason !== 'lost') {
    console.log("Connection closed. Reason: " + reason);
  }
};

connection.open();

export default connection;
```

Modify `createObject` to accept the exported `connection` object. Within the function, check if the connection has opened yet. If it has, then access the current session and call the `call` method with it.

```
// calls.js
async function createObject(connection, obj) {
  if (typeof connection === 'undefined' || !connection?.isOpen) {
    return Promise.reject('No session has been started');
  }

  try {
    const response = await connection.session.call('service.object.create', [], obj);
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
}

export { createObject };
```

I drew up a bit of psuedo code on how you could use this with an API endpoint. Your own implemention might look a bit different, but it illustrates how the `connection` object and `createObject function come together.

```
// app.js
import connection from './connection.js';
import { createObject } from './calls.js';

app.get('/example', async function (req, res) => {
  const obj = { foo: 'bar' };
  
  try {
    const response = await createObject(connection, obj);
    res.send(response);
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would like to know a bit more. I have another file, which contains my API endpoints. After I receive data to the API, in the method, I do some transformation on the data before sending some to `createObject` method, which sends it to autobahn, then some other data is send to `deleteObject`, etc. I gather responses from these methods, which come from autobahn, then transform the data and return it to the user. Do you suggest that I should have `connection.onopen = ..` in the body of my api method, or is there some other way to access the stuff in the `onopen`. Thanks!

Comment: I keep thinking that there is some way to make `session` globally accessible to my API methods so that all of them can send data to the autobahn responsible methods. Is this not how autobahn is supposed to be used?

Comment: I looked a bit more in the docs and it seems like you can get the `session` that is currently active through the `connection` object. It is stored in the `connection.session` property whenever a connection has been succesfully made. I've modified my answer to incorporate this new information.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for all the help on this. I ended up importing the `connection` where my calls are. I skip making the check for `connection` on every method because the file with the connection is enough to ensure that I'm connected to the service. My app is not public. If it was, I see the benefit of checking for connection in every call as you suggested. Thanks again! Looking at it now it makes perfect sense.

Comment: Great to hear and happy to help out!